# Geiger-Muller counter

Tags: particle-physics, ideal-gas, particle-detectors

Why in a Geiger-Muller counter the filling gas has to be at low pressure?
If it was ad high pressure, instead, there will be more gas molecules to be ionized by the approaching radiation and thus the response would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an ionisation chamber an ionising particle pass through the gas and causes ionisation.
An electric field is applied and adjusted to collect as many of the electrons and ions produced by the ionising radiation.

A Geiger-Muller_Tube has gas at about half an atmosphere.
The gas is contained in a metal cylinder and there is a thin cylindrical conductor along the axis of the metal cylinder.
A voltage is applied across the outer (negative) and  inner (positive) conductors of the GM tube which produces an electric field which increases in magnitude towards the centre.

An incoming ionising radiation produces ion and electrons by collision with the gas atoms in the GM-tube.
The key difference from an ionising chamber is that in a GM-tube the electric field is strong enough to accelerate electrons between their collision with the gas atoms and give the electrons enough kinetic energy to cause further ionisation of the gas atoms.
So from very few electrons many more are produced and so when the electrons hit the inner electrode a large, easily detected, electrical pulse is produced.

If the pressure of the gas in the GM-tube is too high that will mean that the neutral atoms are close together and so the electrons accelerated by the electric field will collide with atoms before they have enough kinetic energy to ionise the atoms.
If this happened one would not get avalanche process happening and the output pulse would be very small.

Too low a pressure would mean that there are not enough gas atoms to ionise to produce a reasonable output pulse.

Answer (score 0):

The point in Geiger-Muller counter is not to have maximal amount of material. You can have tubes as small as http://www.imagesco.com/geiger/geiger-counter-tubes.html and if you need bigger sensitivity, you can increase volume. There is also not a big reason to increase the GM sensitivity, you cannot get much information from number of counts per second.

**To the question**: it is more difficult to make a discharge in a higher pressure. At the atmospheric pressure the air can withstand 30kV/cm. At low pressure, however, you can get sparks at few hundred volts, which is much safer and more practical.

Here is a nice text about  it http://www.physics.csbsju.edu/370/jcalvert/dischg.htm.html#Brea, see the picture ilustrating the necessary voltage.

[image]